# How to store data into two tables with same ID?

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to save data into two tables. Table 1 will handle generic data( date, teller, total) and table 2 will handle details data( like pname, pqty, pprice).
I am trying to save these data into two tables with same ID. For moment I am storing data in this way:

```
         {
            conn.Open();


            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtgprofatura.Rows)
            {
                if (!row.IsNewRow)
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insertprofatura", conn);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@shenime", txtshenimi.Text));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@data", DateTime.Now));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@kasieri", lbluser.Text));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NR_F", int.Parse(lblidfatura.Text)));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@emri_sh", lblshitesiemri.Text));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@niptsh", int.Parse(lblshitesinipt.Text)));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@adresash", lbladresashitesi.Text));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@telefonish", lblshitesitelefon.Text));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@emri_b", cmbbleresi.Text));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@niptb", lblbleresinipt.Text));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@adresab", lblbleresiadresa.Text));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@telefonib", lblbleresitelefoni.Text));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nentotali", lblnentotali.Text));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@vleratvsh", lblvleratvsh.Text));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@zbritja", txtzbritja.Text));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@totali", lbltotali.Text));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@barkodi", row.Cells[0].Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@emertimi", row.Cells[1].Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sasia", row.Cells[3].Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cmimi", row.Cells[2].Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@totaliPCS", row.Cells[5].Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tvsh", row.Cells[4].Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@vleratvshpcs", row.Cells[7].Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@patvshpcs", row.Cells[6].Value));
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Procedimi i profatures deshtoi " + ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            clear();
            kRIJOToolStripMenuItem.PerformClick();
        }
```

and the SP used for insertation:

```
    ALTER procedure [dbo].[insertprofatura]
    @shenime varchar(max),
    @data datetime,
    @kasieri varchar(50),
    @NR_F int,
    @emri_sh varchar(50),
    @niptsh varchar(50),
    @adresash varchar(100),
    @telefonish varchar(50),
    @emri_b varchar(50),
    @niptb varchar(50),
    @adresab varchar(100),
    @telefonib varchar(50),
    @nentotali float,
    @zbritja float,
    @vleratvsh float,
    @totali float,
    @barkodi int,
    @emertimi varchar(200),
    @sasia int, 
    @cmimi float,
    @totaliPCS float,
    @tvsh float,
    @vleratvshpcs float,
    @patvshpcs float

    as

    insert into tblprofatura         (NR_F,Shenime,Data,Kasieri,Emri_sh,NIPT_sh,Adresa_sh,Telefoni_sh,Emri_b,NIPT_b,Adresa_b,Telefoni_b,Nentot        ali,Zbritja,VleraTVSH,Totali)
                values(@NR_F,@shenime,@data,@kasieri,@emri_sh,@niptsh,@adresash,@telefonish,@emri_b,@niptb,@adresab,@telefonib,@nentotali,@zbritja,@vleratvsh,@totali)
    insert into tblproofatura_details(NR_F,Barkodi,Emertimi,Cmimi,Sasia,TVSH,Totali,PaTVSHpcs,VleraTVSHpcs)
    values (@NR_F,@barkodi,@emertimi,@cmimi,@sasia,@tvsh,@totaliPCS,@patvshpcs,@vleratvsh)
```

But the main problem from above code is that the bill number( NR_F) is stored via code, not automatically, which it is not a great option( due to clonflict data on dba)
I used the ID field( autonumber, identiy(1,1)). but the id isn't the same. As much product i insert , as much ID will be provided( and where i want to call these data,i cant call by id due to large count of id inserted).
The main question is how do i insert only one row in table 1(date, total, teller), and multiple rows in table 2 (product details), (related to each other by bill number(NR_F)). ONE -TO-MANY

---

Code edited :

```
    ALTER procedure [dbo].[insertimi]

    @shenime varchar(max),
    @data datetime,
    @kasieri varchar(50),
    @emri_sh varchar(50),
    @niptsh varchar(50),
    @adresash varchar(100),
    @telefonish varchar(50),
    @emri_b varchar(50),
    @niptb varchar(50),
    @adresab varchar(100),
    @telefonib varchar(50),
    @nentotali float,
    @zbritja float,
    @vleratvsh float,
    @totali float,
    @barkodi int,
    @emertimi varchar(200),
    @sasia int, 
    @cmimi float,
    @totaliPCS float,
    @tvsh float,
    @vleratvshpcs float,
    @patvshpcs float
    as


    declare @lastId int;
    insert into tblprofatura         (Shenime,Data,Kasieri,Emri_sh,NIPT_sh,Adresa_sh,Telefoni_sh,Emri_b,NIPT_b,Adresa_b,Telefoni_b,Nentotali,Zbritja,VleraTVSH,Totali)
                values(@shenime,@data,@kasieri,@emri_sh,@niptsh,@adresash,@telefonish,@emri_b,@niptb,@adresab,@telefonib,@nentotali,@zbritja,@vleratvsh,@totali)
```

set @lastId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

```
    insert into         tblproofatura_details(NR_F,Barkodi,Emertimi,Cmimi,Sasia,TVSH,Totali,PaTVSHpcs,VleraTVSHpcs)
    values         (@lastId,@barkodi,@emertimi,@cmimi,@sasia,@tvsh,@totaliPCS,@patvshpcs,@vleratvsh)
```

But now inn my parent table for example are being inserted three rows with different ID, and in my child table none row is being inserted. I want in my parent table one row with generic data to be inserted and ni my child table as many rows needed related to parent ID

Comment: Your proc only inserts one row so you can use `SET @MyNewID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to capture the identity value that was just inserted and use it when inserting the child records

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid in my SP i have to statements to insert data. So to clarify more. after statement one where parent are inserted i have to declare "@MyNewID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()" and use it, or how. Because i didn't understand the anwer

Comment: Are you using an identity or not? If you are using an identity you wouldn't be specifying a value for `NR_F` in your insert statement.

Comment: No I'm not using

Comment: I updated my code in question